Why is Aut(Griess algebra) discrete?
Some algebras like the octonions have a continuous Lie group as their automorphism group e.g. $G_2$
According to Wikipedia the automorphism group of the Griess algebra is the Monster group. But that is a discrete group.
Is it true that the Griess algebra has a discrete group as the automorphism group? And if so, why is it not a continuous group?

(All vector spaces, algebras, etc. below are real and finite-dimensional.)
So, let's discuss the following general question: suppose $A$ is a vector space equipped with a multiplication $m : A \otimes A \to A$, about which we assume nothing except bilinearity initially. What can we say about the automorphism group $G = \text{Aut}(A)$?

The first thing to say is that $G$ is always an algebraic group, and also a Lie group. This is because the condition that an invertible linear map $T : A \to A$ preserves the multiplication $m$ (or any other tensor) is a polynomial condition on the entries of $T$ with respect to some basis.
There are plenty of examples where $G$ is a non-discrete algebraic group / Lie group. The simplest one is to take $m = 0$, which gives $G = GL(A)$. More interestingly we can take $A$ to be an associative algebra, in which case $G$ is always at least as large as the inner automorphism group
$$\text{Inn}(A) \cong A^{\times}/Z(A^{\times})$$
of $A$, since the invertible elements of an associative algebra $A$ always act on $A$ by conjugation. If $A$ is central simple over $\mathbb{R}$ then this is the entire automorphism group by the Skolem-Noether theorem; for example, if $A = M_n(\mathbb{R})$ it follows that its automorphism group is the projective general linear group $PGL_n(\mathbb{R})$.
We can in fact show that if $A$ is any noncommutative associative algebra then it has a one-parameter family of inner automorphisms, namely conjugation by $e^{ta}$ where $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \in A$ is not central. Similarly if $A$ is a nonabelian Lie algebra it has a one-parameter family of automorphisms, namely the exponential of any inner derivation $[X, -]$ where $X \in A$ is not central.
However, the Griess algebra is commutative and not associative, so neither of these constructions apply to it; it has no inner automorphisms or inner derivations to speak of.

So, what can we say about automorphisms of commutative algebras? The simplest examples are $A = \mathbb{R}^n$. These behave quite differently from the noncommutative examples above: they have a finite (in particular discrete) group of automorphisms, namely
$$\text{Aut}(A) \cong S_n$$
the symmetric group, acting by permuting the factors. Here is a way to see this which suggests an idea which generalizes to the Griess algebra: $A$ has a finite number of idempotent elements, namely the $2^n$ elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose components are either $0$ or $1$. This is a purely ring-theoretic property, so any automorphism of $A$ necessarily permutes the idempotents. Moreover among them we can isolate the $n$ idempotents $e_i = (0, 0, \dots 1, \dots 0, 0)$ corresponding to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by a purely ring-theoretic property again: they are exactly the primitive idempotents, namely, nonzero idempotents $e$ which can't be written as a sum of two nonzero idempotents $e = e_1 + e_2$ which are orthogonal, meaning that $e_1 e_2 = 0$.
Because being a primitive idempotent is a purely ring-theoretic property, every automorphism of $A$ permutes the $n$ primitive idempotents. And because the primitive idempotents of $A$ form a basis of it, every automorphism of $A$ is in fact determined by what it does to the primitive idempotents. This means $\text{Aut}(A)$ is necessarily a subgroup of the group $S_n$ of all permutations of the primitive idempotents, and it's not hard to see that every permutation is an automorphism, so $\text{Aut}(A) = S_n$ as desired.

Finally, Conway's 1985 paper A simple construction for the Fischer-Griess monster group claims that a similar thing happens for the Griess algebra. Quoting from the introduction:

We shall define certain transposition vectors, and describe the subalgebras generated by any two of them. This leads to a simple proof that the group [of automorphisms of the Griess algebra] is finite, since we can show that there are finitely many transposition vectors.

So, according to Conway, there is a finite set of elements of the Griess algebra, these transposition vectors, which any automorphism must permute (so I assume they are defined in some "purely algebraic" way, like the idempotents above), and presumably he also shows that an automorphism is determined by what it does to these.
